# Lubuntu - G_Is_Dbus_Connection

Tags: ubuntu, lubuntu

I have just installed Lubuntu on VM VirtrualBox.

When I run an app from terminal, eg. firefox, it works but terminal pops up some warnings.

```
maciex@maciex-pc:~$ firefox

(firefox:1152): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:15:43.300: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:34: Expected ')' in color definition

(firefox:1152): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:15:43.300: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:77: Expected ')' in color definition

(firefox:1152): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:15:43.425: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(firefox:1152): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:15:43.425: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(firefox:1152): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:15:43.425: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(firefox:1152): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:15:43.426: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(firefox:1152): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:15:43.426: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
```

It's not about firefox, the same issue with other apps. But if I start the same app not from terminal and then open terminal and run the same app from terminal - I do not have any warnings.

```
maciex@maciex-pc:~$ ps -u maciex
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  829 ?        00:00:00 systemd
  840 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
  865 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-d
  868 ?        00:00:00 lxqt-session
  886 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
  920 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
  950 ?        00:00:00 openbox
  953 ?        00:00:00 at-spi-bus-laun
  960 ?        00:00:00 agent
  964 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd
  969 ?        00:00:00 pcmanfm-qt
  970 ?        00:00:00 lxqt-globalkeys
  971 ?        00:00:00 lxqt-notificati
  972 ?        00:00:00 lxqt-panel
  973 ?        00:00:00 lxqt-policykit-
  974 ?        00:00:00 lxqt-runner
  976 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-fuse
  979 ?        00:00:00 xscreensaver
  990 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
  992 ?        00:00:00 applet.py
 1001 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
 1063 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-trash
 1069 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-udisks2-vo
 1086 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-goa-volume
 1092 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
 1101 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-mtp-volume
 1105 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-afc-volume
 1119 ?        00:00:00 lxqt-powermanag
 1121 ?        00:00:00 qlipper
 1123 ?        00:00:00 nm-tray
 1131 ?        00:00:00 qterminal
 1134 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 1142 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

Could someone explain it? How to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Is the dbus daemon running?

Comment: Well, I think so. I added a screen to my original post.

Comment: Please don't push screenshot pictures; this makes it harder for people.  Instead a cut'n'paste of the contents is preferred.  Thanks!

Comment: This is not an isolated case. Same symptoms here, trying to test [hamster-time-tracker](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster) in an lubuntu-18.10 virtualbox. `dbus-daemon` is running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [noticed by John Little](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2403068&p=13807388#post13807388) (thanks !), this is related to `fcitx`

```
(hamster-cli:4440): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:54:40.431: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
```

`sudo apt purge fcitx-module-dbus` removed the symptom.
Tested in `lubuntu-18.10`, default desktop (`LXQt`).

That's probably https://gitlab.com/fcitx/fcitx/issues/396.

Comment: This removed the error for 90% of the time. But I still get it occasionally. It is flaky.

Comment: Do you mean it happens even without the module (so there would be another source for the same error), or that something is reinstalling it (to check: `sudo apt list fcitx-module-dbus`), which triggers the error again ?

Comment: Yes, it still happens.
https://i.imgur.com/tF75sz5.png

Comment: `fcitx-module-dbus` appear twice your `list` output. How to remove it properly should be found or asked on [stackexchange askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: [apt list](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apt-get-list-packages-are-installed-on-ubuntu-linux/) shows all the modules available to install. If they are installed that will be indicated in front of the name.
Ex:

`kmchmk@UbuntuVirtualBox:~$ sudo apt list python3
Listing... Done
python3/focal,now 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
python3/focal 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 i386
kmchmk@UbuntuVirtualBox:~$ sudo apt list python2
Listing... Done
python2/focal 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 amd64
python2/focal 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 i386
kmchmk@UbuntuVirtualBox:~$ `

So it looks 'fcitx-module-dbus' is not installed.

Comment: Then another package generates the same symptom on your system. Hope you'll find which one !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but in Synaptic I did re-install everything related to Glib and Fcitx and installed Fctix5 and fcitx-dbus-status and the error is gone for all my programs. Sometimes re-install and improve fixes bugs.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind explaining what you mean by "and improve" in "re-install _and improve_"?